# Parallel (CUDA) 2D Poisson solver

Tags: c, cuda, parallel-processing, differential-equations, poisson

I have to solve a 2D Poisson equation using a predictor-corrector scheme. The equation must be solved on a `n*m` non-uniform grid. Predictor-corrector scheme means that the solution `x` at a step `k+1` is obtained by summing the solution at a step `k` and a `delta` value. The `delta` value is obtained by solving a system of linear equations, which is something like:

A(x^k) * delta = b(x^k)

By applying the finite difference method, the matrix `A` has `5` non-null diagonals: the main one, the ones immediately above and below and two further above and below (separated by `n-1` zero-diagonals from the other diagonals). Being non-uniform, `A` is clearly non-symmetric. Also, the main diagonal of `A` and the vector `b` will be changed according the old solution. Now, I'd like to solve this problem using a parallel algorithm, since finding `delta` for big grids can be really expensive. Any ideas? As for now, I'm trying the Jacobi method.

I believe I have two possible paths: I can stick to direct and sequential methods or use an iterative method. If I choose the latter then I have to use Jacobi's method if I want to exploit parallelism. Do you know other parallel methods? If I choose the former, do you know if there is an algorithm that exploits the fact that I have exactly `5` non-zero diagonals? What about Thomas' algorithm for block matrices?

Comment: Do you have any sequential version that you can post?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not authorized to do that. The production code uses LU factorization and forward/backward substitutions to find delta

Comment: You can use `?gbtrf` function from LAPACK to compute LU factorization, and `?gbtrs` to obtain a solution for general (non-symmetric) band matrix. Intel MKL provides a threaded version of these two functions.

Comment: MKL is a possible solution (btw, band matrices are stored row-wise or column-wise? I guess it's the second). I also believe that the current  code is doing a band decomposition, but it's very old, without comments and no indication of what it is doing, so the sooner I get rid of it the happier I am. I've also updated the main question

Comment: Updated C interface for LAPACK can work with both row-wise and column-wise ordering. Also, you can try to use conjugate gradient method. It heavily relies on efficient matrix multiplication algorithm which can be parallel.

Comment: BTW, Intel MKL includes routines for solving PDE (2D and 3D Poisson problems in particular).

Comment: 1) Last time I checked with a debugger, lapack did a transpose operation if the matrix was row-wise.
2) As far as I know, the conjugate gradient method can be applied only to symmetric and positive defined matrices

Comment: I've checked MKL for PDE. I can't use those functions because they require an uniform mesh

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest considering [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html) for solving such kind of problems.

Below I'm reporting a sample code for solving Poisson equation using Jacobi's method in a Cartesian grid. Although the computational grid differs from the one you are interested in, such a sample can give you (and also other Users) an idea on how using CUDA to solve such kind of problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

#define BLOCK_SIZE 32

/********************************/
/* HOST INITIALIZATION FUNCTION */
/********************************/
void init(double * __restrict U, double * __restrict U_old, double * __restrict F, const double x_min, const double x_max, const double y_min, const double y_max, double delta, int Nb)
{
    // --- Initilize grid coordinates
    double x = -1.0;
    double y = -1.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Nb; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {

            F    [i * (Nb) + j] = 0.0;
            U    [i * (Nb) + j] = 0.0;
            U_old[i * (Nb) + j] = 0.0;

            // --- Set radiator temperature in the source box
            if (x <= x_max && x >= x_min && y <= y_max && y >= y_min) F[i * Nb + j] = 200.0;

            // --- Boundary condition on the left, right and upper walls. The boundary condition on the lower wall is vanishing temperature
            if (i == (Nb - 1) || i == 0 || j == (Nb - 1))
            {
                U    [i * (Nb) + j] = 20.0;
                U_old[i * (Nb) + j] = 20.0;
            }
            // --- Update y-grid coordinate
            y += delta;
        }
        // --- Update x-grid coordinate
        x += delta;
        y = -1.0;
    }
}

/*********************************/
/* JACOBI ITERATOR HOST FUNCTION */
/*********************************/
void jacobi_iterator_CPU(const double * __restrict__ U, double * __restrict__ U_old, const double * __restrict__ F, const double delta2, const int Nb)
{
    for (int i=1; i<Nb-1; i++)
        for (int j=1; j<Nb-1; j++)
            U_old[j * Nb + i] = (U[j * Nb + (i - 1)] + U[j * Nb + (i + 1)] + U[(j - 1) * Nb + i] + U[(j + 1) * Nb + i] + (delta2 * F[j * Nb + i])) * 0.25;

}

/***********************************/
/* JACOBI ITERATOR KERNEL FUNCTION */
/***********************************/
__global__ void jacobi_iterator_GPU(const double * __restrict__ U, double * __restrict__ U_old, const double * __restrict__ F, const double delta2, const int Nb)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (i < Nb - 1 && j < Nb - 1 && i > 0 && j > 0)
    {
        U_old[j * Nb + i] = (U[j * Nb + (i - 1)] + U[j * Nb + (i + 1)] + U[(j - 1) * Nb + i] + U[(j + 1) * Nb + i] + (delta2 * F[j * Nb + i])) * 0.25;

    }
}

/***************************/
/* DISPLAY MATRIX FUNCTION */
/***************************/
void print_matrix(int N, double *M)
{
    int Nb = N + 2;
    int i, j;
    for (i = Nb - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++)
        {
            printf("%.2f\t", M[j * Nb + i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    // --- The computation domain is [-1, 1] x [-1, 1]

    const int N         = 16;                           // --- Grid size is N x N
    const int Nb        = N + 2;                        // --- Grid side including the boundaries is Nb x Nb
    const int MAX_ITER  = 1000;                         // --- Maximum number of iterations

    // --- Defining the source box
    double x_min = 0.0;
    double x_max = 1.0 / 3.0;
    double y_min = -2.0 / 3.0;
    double y_max = -1.0 / 3.0;

    double delta        = 2.0 / ((double)N - 1.0);      // --- Discretization step

    // --- Allocating host memory variables
    double *h_U             = (double *)malloc(Nb * Nb * sizeof(double));
    double *h_U_old         = (double *)malloc(Nb * Nb * sizeof(double));
    double *h_F             = (double *)malloc(Nb * Nb * sizeof(double));

    // --- Allocating device memory variables
    double *d_U;            gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_U,      Nb * Nb * sizeof(double)));
    double *d_U_old;        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_U_old,  Nb * Nb * sizeof(double)));
    double *d_F;            gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_F,      Nb * Nb * sizeof(double)));

    // --- Dummy pointer for pointer swapping
    double *temp;

    // --- Host array initialization
    init(h_U, h_U_old, h_F, x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max, delta, Nb);

    // --- Copying arrays from host to device
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_U,       h_U,        Nb * Nb * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_U_old,   h_U_old,    Nb * Nb * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_F,       h_F,        Nb * Nb * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Host iterations
    for (int h = 0; h < MAX_ITER; h++)
    {
        jacobi_iterator_CPU(h_U, h_U_old, h_F, delta * delta, Nb);

        // --- Pointers swap
        temp = h_U;
        h_U = h_U_old;
        h_U_old = temp;
    }

    printf("Host results\n");
    print_matrix(N, h_U);

    // --- Device iterations
    dim3 DimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 DimGrid(iDivUp(N, BLOCK_SIZE), iDivUp(N, BLOCK_SIZE));

    for (int h = 0; h < MAX_ITER; h++)
    {
        jacobi_iterator_GPU<<<DimGrid, DimBlock>>>(d_U, d_U_old, d_F, delta * delta, Nb);

        // --- Pointers swap
        temp = d_U;
        d_U = d_U_old;
        d_U_old = temp;
    }

    // --- Move device result to the host
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_U, d_U, Nb * Nb * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("Device results\n");
    print_matrix(N, h_U);

    // --- Freeing host memory
    free(h_U);
    free(h_U_old);
    free(h_F);

    // --- Freeing device memory
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_U));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_U_old));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_F));

    return 0;
}
```

The `Utilities.cu` and `Utilities.cuh` files needed to run such an example are mantained at [this](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/CUDA_Utilities) github page and are omitted here.